# Problema ao utilizar append js elemento não aparece

Tags: javascript, jquery

pessoal estou com um probleminha no meu `append` no `js` eu precisava substituir uma imagem por outra quando eu clicar em uma `div` ai quando eu clico a imagem setada via ID some normal porem a que deveria aparecer no lugar não aparece eu precisava que ela aparece no mesmo lugar da imagem que oculto segue meu código:

```
$('#lp-pom-image-1674').on('click', function(e) {
    $('#lp-pom-image-186').fadeOut('fast', function(){
        $('#lp-pom-image-186').append('<img src="http://d9hhrg4mnvzow.cloudfront.net/unbouncepages.com/home-                    teste/f6ffe5b8-logo-www-outubro.png" class="logo-center-outubro">');
    });
  });
```

Percebam que nome código no evento de click do id `#lp-pom-image-1674` a imagem com o id `#lp-pom-image-186` tem que sumir e ele some normalmente e nesse mesmo id ele da um `append` onde ele teria que colocar a minha imagem que esta dentro do `img` mais simplesmente não aparece isso precisa ser feito dessa forma alguem pode me ajudar?

Comment: Tente dar um `$( "#lp-pom-image-186" ).empty();` antes do `append`.

Comment: O problema não é porque você está dando um append em um elemento que acabou de receber o .fadeOut? Assim ele fica invisível e não aparece o que foi dado append.

Comment: ficaria assim $('#lp-pom-image-186').empty().append('<img="teste">')

Comment: @RenatoDiniz Então eu pensei nisso e reamente é isso se eu der um append em outro elemento ele funciona de boa so que ele fica no lugar errado ele tem que ficar no mesmo lugar que estava a imagem anterior a ele entende por isso tenho que usar o mesmo id que recebeu o fade

Comment: Então depois do append exiba novamente o elemento

Comment: @RenatoDiniz com Fade in? é que ainda to aprendendo =3

Comment: @RenatoDiniz como ficaria? isso poderia por como resposta para eu entender melhor ?

Comment: Isso, faça o que o amigo acima falou, primeiro faça o .empty(), depois o append e depois um .fadeIn()

Comment: Vou colocar como resposta

Comment: @RenatoDiniz legal se puder fazer o código apra eu ver como fica agradeço

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você deve mostrar novamente a div que acabou de receber o .fadeOut, pois agora ela estará com display:none, ou seja, invisível. Antes de dar o append faça também uma limpeza da div com o .empty(), assim:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#teste').on('click', function(e) {
    $('#some').fadeOut('fast', function() {
      $('#some').empty();
      $('#some').append('<p>Opa, isso apareceu</p>');
      $('#some').fadeIn();
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="teste">Trocar elemento</button>

<div id="some">
  <p>Isso daqui vai sumir</p>
</div>
```

Em vez do `.empty()` e do `.append()`, você pode usar também o `.html()`, que já substitui o conteúdo da div diretamente.

Comment: Amigo obrigado pela resposta mais tipo acho que tem algum problema pois eu clico e meu elemento some mais não aparece o novo o que pode ser esse link e onde estou realizando os testes disso vc pode acessar e ver você mesmo por favor? basta clicar na setinha da direita ai vc vai ver o logo do header sumindo e o outro logo precisava parecer mais nao aparece http://unbouncepages.com/home-teste/

Comment: deixa queto acho que ja achei o problema

Answer (score 1):

Sugiro em vez de mudar a imagem toda, trocar somente o `src` e usar o `load` para só começar o próximo fadeIn depois de a imagem estar carregada.

Assim:

```js
$('#lp-pom-image-1674').on('click', function(e) {
  $('#lp-pom-image-186').fadeOut(function() {
    $(this).load(function() {
      $(this).fadeIn();
    }).attr("src", "http://d9hhrg4mnvzow.cloudfront.net/unbouncepages.com/home-teste/f6ffe5b8-logo-www-outubro.png");
  });
});
```